# How to change start point of animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the start point of the SVG path animation. I am a beginner in SVG paths, so might be a dumb question. Currently, the animation I have does the opposite of what I want. I need the path animation to start from the bottom circle and go to the top circle. I have tried the `width:0` trick to do this but it does the opposite of what I want. Can anyone help me out?
[If code doesn't work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zL-ny78DRQ-ETgk4CLoMmqgTXMJjT_Br/view?usp=sharing)
**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        .forward-line {
            stroke-dasharray: 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 19;
            stroke-dashoffset: 300;
            animation: dash 5s linear 0s reverse infinite,  appear 5s linear 0s;
        }

        .reverse-line {
            stroke-dasharray: 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 19;
            stroke-dashoffset: 300;
            animation: dash 5s linear 0s forwards infinite,  appear 5s linear 0s;
            /* animation: appear 5s linear 0s;  */
        }

        @keyframes dash {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 300;
            }

            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }

        @keyframes appear{
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                width: 0%;
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <svg width="200" height="200" style="display: block;margin-left: 2%;">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
            <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <svg class="forward-line" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute;top: 0px;z-index: -10;">
        <!--STARTING-X  STARTING-Y q CURVE-WIDTH CURVE-HEIGHT ENDPOINT-X ENPOINT-Y-->
        <path d="M 100 100 q 150 150 300 100 q 150 -50 250 100 q 150 150 300 100 q 150 -50 250 100" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
    </svg>
    <div>
        <svg width="200" height="200" style="margin-left: 45%;">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg width="200" height="200" style="margin-left: 90%;">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```